# Multiplying complex function by a real function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

In [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Integration_by_Substitution) proof which I have screenshotted below, why are we able to multiply the real function $\phi'(u)$ by the real valued complex function $f(\phi(u))$? This feels wrong to me and I feel that I have some foundational misunderstanding that is preventing me from feeling this is ok to do formally.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware that any complex number can be multiplied by any real number? In fact, every real number is also a complex number.

So thus it is also possible to pointwise multiply a complex function by a real valued one. In fact, if $f=f_1+if_2$ for realvalued functions $f_1,f_2$ we have $\phi'f=\phi'f_1+i\phi'f_2$.

Thus $\phi'$ can be drawn out of the real part and the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$ is a real function, then so is $\phi'$. That is, each number $\phi'(u)$ is a real number. And, if $z\in\Bbb C$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$,$$\operatorname{Re}(z)\lambda=\operatorname{Re}(\lambda z)\quad\text{and}\quad\operatorname{Im}(z)\lambda=\operatorname{Im}(\lambda z).$$Now, apply this with $z=f\bigl(\phi(u)\bigr)$ and $\lambda=\phi'(u)$.

Comment: Why are we able to multiply a real number by a complex number? Is there an algebraic explanation for this?

Comment: Because we can multiply any two complex numbers and because any real number is also a complex number. Or are you suggesting that it makes no sense to multiply $3$ by $i$?